# Pandas df to dictionary with values as python lists aggregated from a df column

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I have a pandas df containing 'features' for stocks, which looks like this:

[image: features for stocks previous to training neural net]

I am now trying to create a dictionary with **unique sector** as **key**, and a **python list of tickers** for that unique sector as **values**, so I end up having something that looks like this:

```
{'consumer_discretionary': ['AAP',
  'AMZN',
  'AN',
  'AZO',
  'BBBY',
  'BBY',
  'BWA',
  'KMX',
  'CCL',
  'CBS',
  'CHTR',
  'CMG',
```

etc.

I could iterate over the pandas df rows to create the dictionary, but I prefer a  more pythonic solution. Thus far, this code is a partial solution:

```
df.set_index('sector')['ticker'].to_dict()
```

Any feedback is appreciated.

**UPDATE:**

The solution by @wrwrwr

```
df.set_index('ticker').groupby('sector').groups
```

partially works, but it returns a **pandas series** as a the value, instead of a **python list**. Any ideas about how to transform the pandas series into a python list in the same line and w/o having to iterate the dictionary?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wouldn't `f.set_index('ticker').groupby('sector').groups` be what you want?

For example:

```
f = DataFrame({
        'ticker': ('t1', 't2', 't3'),
        'sector': ('sa', 'sb', 'sb'),
        'name': ('n1', 'n2', 'n3')})

groups = f.set_index('ticker').groupby('sector').groups
# {'sa': Index(['t1']), 'sb': Index(['t2', 't3'])}
```

To ensure that they have the type you want:

```
{k: list(v) for k, v in f.set_index('ticker').groupby('sector').groups.items()}
```

or:

```
f.set_index('ticker').groupby('sector').apply(lambda g: list(g.index)).to_dict()
```

Comment: Thank you @wrwrwr, almost there! your solution is excellent but it does not quite return a python list as the value, but a pandas series as the value. I could take it from here and loop the dictionary to transform the pandas series into a list, but again, that's what I was avoiding. I'm looking for a pythonic, one liner solution. Do you know how to transform the pandas series into a python list in the same line? i.e: f.set_index('ticker').groupby('sector').groups.tolist() (that does not work)

Comment: use `list()` method to convert to list

Comment: I'm not sure why are you getting series as values, but still extended the answer with some rather brutal approaches to enforcing that they are lists.

Comment: Updated for Pandas 0.19 (which seems to have switched from plain lists to indices for `groups` values).

Comment: Great answer. Thanks